# JavaFx: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Tags: java, javafx-2, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

I am tring to create a file in C:\Program Files folder using javaFX, but it show me an error of access denied.

This is the code sample.

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Folder\\my_file.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("Hello!");
```

---

This is the error which I found while running the application.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\My Folder\my_file.txt (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
```

I don't know how to allow my application with all the required permission to create files at specified location. Please help me with sufficient codes and information.

Comment: Hi, may be you can try to another location like "My Document". Is it works? what version of windows you use? XP? Win 7? Win 8? how if you manually create file using windows explorer?

Comment: Check whether you have necessary access to create file in the specified location. Also add flush the content after writing it on the writer `out.flush(); fstream.close();` .This given code should work.

Comment: @DanielRobertus, I want to use the directory where the application is installed. This error I found in win7 but I need to make it for all os (Mac and Windows)

Comment: @Meherzad, No I don't have that permission but when I start my application with 'Run as Administrator' it allows me to create file and application runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @ShreyasDave : Please check that folder security, do you have full control permission? i think its more about windows security issue than your code. you need to allow full permission for user who will make that file. Or you can simply save your file in User document folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't explicitly disabled UAC you will not be able to write to `Program Files`. The OS will prevent that to protect your system.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: will it work ?? and please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: No, disabling UAC requires administrator intervention.  That's the whole point of UAC.  On a Linux system you cannot write into `/bin` unless you have root access. The same applies to Win7 and later.